# Is it there a way to pass custom parameters to useFactory DynamicModules in NestJs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a shared library that is going to provide modules to other applications. So I need dynamic custom params to generate custom instances for each module inside an application.

I already opened an issue for this in the official repo 
[nestjs/issues/1965](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1965), but maybe someone here can get me some ideas or help me out with this.

I already looked up nestjs documentation and also read the code and issues, but I can't find a way to dynamically get parameters from the instantiation process to generate custom instances of what ever I want.

So basically what I need is provide an string that can get into the instantiation process so the instance returned will use the string to scope the module's configuration. So what I'm currently doing is hacking into Nest's instances to inject the scope into it, which I think is not the best thing to do.

Here is the code sample I made for the issue:

**Library code**

```js
// decorator
export function Configurable(scope: string) {
  return (target: object, key: string | symbol, index?: number) => {
    const meta = Reflect.getMetadata(CONFIGURABLE_METADATA, target) || {};
    let dependencies = meta.dependencies || [];

    dependencies = [...dependencies, { scope, key }];

    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      CONFIGURABLE_METADATA,
      { dependencies },
      target,
    );

    Inject(CONFIGURATION_PROVIDER_TOKEN)(target, key, index);
  };
}
```

```js
// explorer service
@Injectable()
export class ExplorerService {
  constructor(private readonly modulesContainer: ModulesContainer) {}

  injectScopes(): void {
    const providers = [...this.modulesContainer.values()]
      .map((module: NestModule) => {
        return [...module.providers.values()];
      }).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);

    providers.forEach(provider => {
      const { instance } = provider;

      if (!instance && !instance.constructor) {
        return;
      }

      // custom metadata
      const meta = Reflect.getMetadata(CONFIGURABLE_METADATA, instance.constructor);

      if (meta) {
        meta.dependencies.forEach(dep => {
          const { index, scope } = dep;
          const wrapper = provider[INSTANCE_METADATA_SYMBOL].dependencies[index];
          const { instance: depInstance } = wrapper;
          Object.defineProperty(depInstance, 'scope', { value: scope });
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Application code (using the library)**

```js
// usage in the application
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigurationModule.forRoot(factoryOptions)],
  providers: [UserConfigProvider],
  exports: [ConfigurationModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// user config provider
@Injectable()
export class AssessmentConfiguration {
  constructor(
    @Configurable('common')
    private readonly commonConfig: ConfigurationService,
    @Configurable('users')
    private readonly usersConfig: ConfigurationService,
  ) {}
}
```

Appreciate any help I can get or any discussion we can generate from this. If there is something missing I can provide more information or context.